# How to ensure the FieldValue.serverTimestamp() finish executing in Cloud Firestore before I get the latest data on my listener?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm coding in Flutter and I'm updating a document in my Cloud Firestore

```
// Prepare the data
final Map<String, dynamic> data = {
        'name': newName,
        'lastUpdate': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      };

// Update the data in Firestore
await documentReference.updateData(data);
```

I also have a subscription that listens to that `documentReference` like this:

```
subscription = documentReference
         .snapshots().listen((){});

subscription.onData(printSnapshotData);
```

What happen is I only update the data once but I will get two data reads on my listener.
The first one is like this:

```
name: 'newName'
lastUpdated: null
```

The second one is like this:

```
name: 'newName'
lastUpdated: Timestamp(seconds=1594368407, nanoseconds=376000000)
```

So it seems that there was a delay between the first one and the second one and the app gets the data twice.

What I want is to get the data after the `Timestamp` in the `lastUpdated` field is done. Only read once is enough because the first data is useless for me. How to do that ?

Thank you!

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. Is there any other place you are creating that document?

Comment: Nope. That is the only place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you are getting two updates on your listener is expected, and that behavior can't be changed.  Listeners always fire immediately with local changes, then again every time the data has changed.  Since the SDK doesn't know the final value of the timestamp before it's written, it will invoke once without the final value, then again with the final server timestamp.  The first callback doesn't cost any document reads - it is working purely with local data.

If you want to know if the snapshot delivered to your callback comes from the server, you will have to check the data in the snapshot to see if it contains what you need.

For more detailed information about how server timestamps work, [read this blog post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-secrets-of-firestores-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-revealed-29dd7a38a82b).

Comment: Thanks for the new info Doug. In case where local data is same as server data - are we charged for a read?

Comment: You are only charged for a read when something on the server changes (compared to the client), which causes the document to be re-read by an active listener.

Comment: I used Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now().toUtc()) instead of FieldValue.serverTimestamp() to avoid double call_back. is this solution ok?

Answer (score 0):

Further to Doug extremely informative answer. I wanted to add that it is possible to use the snapshots metadata's `hasPendingWrites` property to filter out the local updates before the timestamp is added. See example below.

```dart
subscription = documentReference
    .snapshots()
    .where((snapshot) => !snapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrites)
    .listen((snapshot){
      // Your code here    
    });
```